# My xpath apply returns NULL value

Tags: xml, r, xpath, web-scraping, rcurl

I am trying to build a web crawler and extract information for the website 
"http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/home/home.do".

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)

url     <- "http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/home/home.do"
page    <- getURL(url)
parsed  <- htmlTreeParse(page, useInternalNodes = TRUE)

extract <- xpathApply(
    parsed, 
    "//*/href[@id='navbar-collapse-RCSB']/ul/li"
)
```

This is the code i have used for going into the "Search" tab in the above website
After executing this code I am getting a Null or empty list.
How can I extract my data from such websites.

Comment: Why are you scraping when the provide a [REST API](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/software/rest.do) to their data?

Comment: I'm totally new to this and this might be a bit ambitious for me, but what can we do with the API ?

Comment: There is a pretty decent explanation on that page. What exactly are you scraping for (i.e. what are you planning on "entering" in the search box to then scrape once the results come back)?

Comment: I see, so my next step would be to Integrate this API in R and retrieve data from this website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question does not specify what output is wanted but maybe this will get you started:

```
library(XML)
url <- "http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/home/home.do"
doc <- htmlTreeParse(url, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
xp <- xpathApply(doc, "//*/div[@id='navbar-collapse-RCSB']/ul/li")
```

Comment: I am having problem with the synatx, for example if the Xpath is
" <a href = "#" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> ...<a>
How do I write such paths 
Xp <- xpathApply(doc,"//*/href[@class = 'dropdown-toggle']")?

Comment: Perhaps you want: `xpathApply(doc, "//*/div[@id='navbar-collapse-RCSB']/ul/li/a[@class='dropdown-toggle']")` or maybe `xpathApply(doc, "//a[@class='dropdown-toggle']")`

Comment: Still returns  a Null value

Comment: It does not produce NULL for me.  Maybe you have a typo.  Copy the code from the answer to the clipboard and paste it into R.

Comment: webpage.data <- getURL(webpage)
webpage.tc <- textConnection(webpage.data)
webpage_readlines <- readLines(webpage.tc)
webpage_parse <- htmlTreeParse(webpage_readlines,useInternalNodes = T)
webpage_list <- unlist(xpathApply(webpage_parse,"//*/a[@class='navbar-collapse-RCSB']"))
This is the one I'm trying

Comment: I was able to access all the href in the xml, my next step would be to match the required href and scrape the data from there